# Regex not working,

Tags: php, regex

I have a a regex like this:

```
  preg_match_all('!>Download</a>(.*?)</span>!i', $file, $c);
```

and it matches everything when there is more than one occurrence in the file for example:

```
   Download</a>
<br>
<span style="font-size:11px; color:#1F242A; font-weight:normal;">http://filec.com/file/1752396291/g.rar.html</span> 

   Download</a>
<br>
<span style="font-size:11px; color:#1F242A; font-weight:normal;">http://filec.com/file/1752396291/g.rar.html</span>
```

but when theres only one of the download links on the page it wont match up anything.

Ive tried preg_match and looked into other possibilities but nothings work as of yet .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

james

Comment: What are you trying to extract/match?

Comment: How about !>Download</a>([^<]?)</span>!

Comment: anything between Download</a>
 and </span> 
it works when there is more than one on the page if not it does not match it at all

Comment: Here is a neat tool for testing as you go. http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: Chances are the `/` in being intepreted literally, try escaping it as `\/`

Comment: @ woodzu that regex doesnt match any thing for me

Comment: Try `!is` flag if the area includes linebreaks. And your shown examples do not include the expected `>` immediately before `Download`.

Comment: Can you post the code you get when there's just one (whatever that is)

Comment: @  johnluetke its just spitting out the same result

Comment: preg_match_all('!>Download</a>(.*?)<\/span>!i', $file, $c); thats the code thats being used to match up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the dotall `s` flag if you want `.` to match linebreaks:

```
!>Download</a>(.*?)</span>!is;
```

Also, I don't see a `>` before your `Download`. So you might want to take that out too:

```
!Download</a>(.*?)</span>!is;
```

Comment: thank you it worked !! what does the is do at the end please ? just so i can understand what it is doing ?

Comment: @Jamesmiller `i` makes the search case-insensitive, while `s` is the "dotall"-flag, so that `.` matches newlines as well as other characters.

Comment: Thank you that helps hope all is well